# Unable to download MNIST data - tensorflow tutorial

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, mnist

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot = True)
```

when I try this code

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\some_random_alphanum_folder'
occurs
(of course, Username and some_random_alphanum_folder is not actual name)
I tried even on administator mode, but it didn't help.
My tensorflow version is CPU only, 0.12rc0 for windows, python 3.5
and python version is 3.5.2

edit: fixed on tensorflow 0.12.0 rc1

Comment: can you create the dir manually?

Comment: the random alphanum folder changes all the time, so I can't try that.

Comment: try one that is reported not to work. that's not a workaround, that's to see if you can do it manually.

Comment: I tried others like "MNIST_data" instead of "MNIST_data/" or "import input_data" instead of "from ... import input_data"